# dealing with flow while scaling rabbitmq

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I have two applications (let's call them A and B) in a pipeline.

App A is a Spring Boot / Spring Integration app that reads messages X from queue 1, does some work, and emits a large number of messages Y into queue 2 based -- for each X from queue 1, about 300 Y will be published to 2. A single thread handles the work in each X and publishing the individual messages. Optimizing app A has gotten me to a place where a single instance can acknowledge about 50 X per second; thus publishing about 15k Y per second to queue 2.

App B is also a Spring Boot / Spring Integration app that reads Ys from queue 2, and aggregates them, finishing the pipeline. A single instance of B handles about 7-8k Y per second.

So, in summary, with 1 A, 2 Bs, and a pretty large RabbitMQ server (an AWS [r3.4xlarge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)), I hit about 50 X and 15000 Y a second.

I have been trying to scale up this process; at a minimum, I'd like to hit 100 X / 30000 Y per second. Because the logic in these apps is suitable for scaling horizontally, I've been trying to double the deployment; i.e. 2 As and 4 Bs.

However, scaling up the As doesn't have the effect expected; acknowledgements of Xs stays roughly steady at 50/s and Ys also stay steady at about 15k a second, with queue 2 remaining more or less empty.

Closer inspection reveals that A's publishing channels are in `flow` mode, presumably because 15k a second is a lot to be cramming into queue 2. However, the limitation doesn't seem to be just a queue receiving 15k Y a second; if I set change the bindings so that the Ys are instead published to a queue without any consumers, I hit the expected 100 X / 30k Y a second.

**Why can't I seem to get 30k Y a second into queue 2?**

Additional details:

- queue 2 is declared as durable with a DLX
- Y messages are published as non-persistent

The publisher declaration looks like:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageConverter jsonNodeMessageConverter,
                                    AmqpHeaderMapper headerMapper) {
    RabbitTemplate outboundTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    outboundTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonNodeMessageConverter);

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(BeanNames.OUTPUT_CHANNEL)
            .split()
            .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(outboundTemplate)
                    .exchangeName(OUTBOUND_EXCHANGE_NAME)
                    .headerMapper(headerMapper)
                    .routingKeyExpression("headers." + ApplicationHeaders.DESTINATION_ROUTING_KEY))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public AmqpHeaderMapper headerMapper() {
    return new DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper() {
        @Override
        protected void populateStandardHeaders(Map<String, Object> headers, MessageProperties amqpMessageProperties) {
            super.populateStandardHeaders(headers, amqpMessageProperties);
            amqpMessageProperties.setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        }
    };
}
```

**update**

I can flesh out more of my settings here.

For application A:

- consumers / threads: 16
- prefetch for X in application A: 50
- no publisher acknowledgements
- non-persistent

For application B:

- consumers / threads: 16
- prefetch for Y in application B: 250
- tx size: 250

In RabbitMQ (which I've upgraded to an r3.8xlarge):

- Erlang VM threads up to 384 (32 cores x 12)
- tcp recbuf and sndbuf set to 192kb per https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html
- sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=8192

I've even split the flows at this point; two application A's read off one queue 1 but publish to two queue 2s -- 2a and 2b. The acks/s on queue 1 hasn't changed at all, and the sum of acks/s on 2a and 2b is the same as it was when there was just one queue 2. Indeed, the connections from application A to the rabbit and the channels from application A to queues 2a and 2b still routinely go into `flow`.

All that's changed is I use even less hardware resources than before (because I upgraded the rabbit server) -- the rabbit never spikes over 30% CPU and the memory use stays ridiculously low.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not using transactional channels on the producer side.

Try increasing the `prefetchCount` and `txSize` on the Y consumer listener containers; the first will buffer messages in the container; the second will reduce the ack traffic.

**EDIT**

For RabbitMQ specifics, see 
[Finding bottlenecks with RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/).

Comment: I already had prefetchCount set to around 250 but I'll jack that up and try boosting the tx size a bunch.

Comment: This link was just posted to the rabbitmq-users google group in response to another question; https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/

Comment: Here's a link to the complete thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/DjRtCaqNNuI

Comment: Yep; I've been looking at that link a lot and also tuning for throughput on https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html, but to no particular avail thus far. I'm definitely in the second scenario it describes -- connections and channels in flow mode, but not the queues. However, the CPU on the server is fine and there's no perceivable disk load, presumably because the messages aren't persistent.

Comment: Hi Gary -- I'm still stumped by the above despite your earlier help; I've clarified all of my settings. If you get a chance and have any thoughts or hints, I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: You don't say what version you're using. If you have high concurrency on the producer side you might need to increase the channel cache size so channels are reused. 1.6 has a more reasonable cache size of 100; earlier versions only cache 1 channel so you can get a lot of channel churn, which hurts performance. You could also try changing the cache mode to CONNECTION so each producer gets his own connection. Beware, though, that auto-declaration of queues etc is not supported with that mode, so you might need two connection factories.